# Orbeon Forms: Paste Date into Control from Clipboard

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to have a button in the form that pastes the data from the clipboard into a specified text control?

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature at this time. It is technically possible to do this, of course, and in fact the opposite is already present in the upcoming 2023.1 release, where you can *copy* the content of a text field or textarea using an optional button next to the field.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response..

Although its not a feature at this time, how would we go about doing this?

We are especially interested in pasting the data from a mobile device (e.g. apple/android) into a form field.

Many thanks.

Comment: Pete, are you referring to pasting data *on* on a mobile device, or *from* a mobile device  *to* a laptop or desktop?

Comment: The users are using mobile devices and need to "cut-out" some pre-formatted data from another app and "paste" it into the Orbeon form (on the same device).

We think it would be a better user experience if we provide a button to "paste" the data into the form field rather than using the native device functionality which is a little more cumbersome..

PeteA

Comment: Any suggestions would be most welcome..

Comment: Pete, the standard way to do it with Orbeon Forms would be to add an option to Form Builder to add a "Paste" button/icon to text fields, in the same way we  now have an option to add a "Copy" icon. However this would require implementation work.

Comment: My requirement is to paste data into and Orbeon forms field using a button.

Here is a test form where the "Copy Text" button which correctly stores the text in the clipboard. However, it's the part the second we need using the "Paste Text" button - this part does not work curently.

PeteA

https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/8c236de86747d789de49ed7ae0fad2bbb2df4bde

Comment: Pete, understood, I see what you are doing here. In general, setting the value of a readonly form control will not work for security reasons. Only setting the value of a read-write form controls will work. In this case, can you make the field read-write? Bypassing the security constraints of a readonly field would require this to be explicit from the point of view of the form author, that is this would have to be made a specific option on the field, which means implementing a few feature.

Comment: Hi Erik,
I've changed the control to read-write - but still no luck.
I would have expected that the button "action"  (type="javascript") would have executed the javascript to read the clipboard data.
Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Pete, this seems to work for me on demo now. But note that we have upgraded the site to Orbeon Forms 2023.1. Does it work for you as well?